# Job Title doesn't match Description on jobs.serverfault.com

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

The job title for [this posting](http://jobs.serverfault.com/?5581) is listed as "Sr. Software Administrator".

But the description says:
"The IT Services Division is seeking a **Senior Security Systems Administrator**.",

which sounds like what the job title is actually about.  Might want to notify them and see if it is mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be filed with fog creek, I'll mail it to them.

http://www.fogcreek.com/Contact.html